# Apache directory configuration when installing nominatim

Tags: apache-httpd, openstreetmap

I have installed a Nominatim server sticking to [this excellent walk through](http://koo.fi/blog/2015/03/19/openstreetmap-nominatim-server-for-geocoding/). However, I am not able to get the apache configuration to work.

my default-conf is specified as follows:

```
    ServerName maps.example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory "/var/www/html/nominatim">
     Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AddType text/html .php
    </Directory>
```

In Nominatim I specify the BaseUrl as:

```
 @define('CONST_Website_ @define('CONST_Website_BaseURL', '$IP/html/nominatim/')
```

setting up the server via:

```
 ./utils/setup.php --create-website /var/www/html/nominatim
Symlinks created
```

returns

```
WARNING: Unable to access the website at 46.101.185.214/html/nominatim/
You may want to update settings/local.php with @define('CONST_Website_BaseURL', 'http://[HOST]/[PATH]/');
Setup finished.
```

However, the server is accessible http://$IP/html/nominatim/index.php yet it looks somewhat awkward.

Trying the search returns:

```
Not Found 404
```

I guess the problem is the apache configuration but i cannot find a working constellation. One hint might be the url after klicking "search":

```
http://$IP/html/nominatim/$IP/html/nominatim/$IP/html/nominatim/search.php?q=test&viewbox=
```

Therefore my question: What do I have to change in my configuration files in order to get this working?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out on [Github](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/issues/369) the answer is really simple:

the `http://` was missing within the Nominatim definition. It should have read:

```
@define('CONST_Website_ @define('CONST_Website_BaseURL', 'http://$IP/html/nominatim/')
```